# Swift Array random insertion and removal very slow

Tags: arrays, swift, performance, insert

I need to work with huge arrays (over a billion items), in which to store (unordered) indexes of big data (in the order of petabytes and stored on a matrix of SSD).
The size of the arrays does not vary much (max 10-15%), but many insertion/removal operations are required on them.
With some tests I found a frightening slowness, even for smaller dimensions (10 million elements) which - initially - I attributed to an incorrect tuning of the SSD controllers.
In researching the bottleneck, I wrote some software to identify where the problem was.
I found it in the **insert(_:at:)** and **remove(at:)** functions (both for **Array** and also for **ContiguousArray**).
To verify how serious the problem was, I wrote a benchmark program that check how much time is spent - with arrays of 1, 10 and 100 million elements - for an incremental number of "removal/insertion" pairs in random positions.
In order to be able to reproduce the test, the data with which to operate (and the positions where to do the removals and insertions) I obtain them from a random number generator suitably seeded.

```
import Foundation
import GameplayKit
import CryptoKit

// Parameters - begin -------------------------------------------------------------------------
let ELEMENTS  : Int = 1_000_000   // and 10_000_000 and 100_000_000, also used as seed for the random number generator
let ROUND_MAX : Int = (1 << 30)   // 1_073_741_824
// Parameters - end -------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Some output formatting aid - begin -------------------------------------------------------------------------
extension String {
  func leftPadding (_ length : Int) -> String {
    if (length > self.count) {
      return (String (repeating : " ", count : (length - self.count)) + self)
    }
    else {
      return (self)
    }
  }
}
let formatterInt    : NumberFormatter = { let numberFormatter : NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter ()
                                          numberFormatter.format                = "#,##0"
                                          return (numberFormatter)                                   } ()
let formatterDouble : NumberFormatter = { let numberFormatter : NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter ()
                                          numberFormatter.format                = "#,##0.000"
                                          return (numberFormatter)                                  } ()
// Some output formatting aid - end -------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Random generator and time sample initialization - begin -------------------------------------------------------------------------
let randomizer       : GKARC4RandomSource = GKARC4RandomSource (seed : String (ELEMENTS).data (using : String.Encoding.utf8)!)
var machTimebaseInfo : mach_timebase_info = mach_timebase_info ()
mach_timebase_info (&(machTimebaseInfo))
var elapsed : UInt64 = 0 // nanoseconds
// Random generator and time sample initialization - end -------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Array initialization and preload - begin -------------------------------------------------------------------------
var array : Array<Int> = Array<Int> ()
array.reserveCapacity (ELEMENTS)
while (array.count < ELEMENTS) {
  array.append (randomizer.nextInt ())
}
// Array initialization and preload - end -------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Header output - begin -------------------------------------------------------------------------
print ("\nArray size : \(formatterInt.string (for : ELEMENTS)!) elements\n")
print ("       Rounds        Elapsed (s)                                                     Hash (SHA256)")
// Header output - end -------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Benchmark - begin -------------------------------------------------------------------------
var limit   : Int = 1
var counter : Int = 0
repeat {
  let start : UInt64 = ((mach_absolute_time () * UInt64 (machTimebaseInfo.numer)) / UInt64 (machTimebaseInfo.denom)) // nanoseconds
  // Test section begin -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  array.remove (at : randomizer.nextInt (upperBound : ELEMENTS))
  array.insert (randomizer.nextInt (), at : randomizer.nextInt (upperBound : ELEMENTS))
  // Test section end -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  let stop : UInt64 = ((mach_absolute_time () * UInt64 (machTimebaseInfo.numer)) / UInt64 (machTimebaseInfo.denom)) // nanoseconds
  elapsed += (stop - start)
  counter += 1
  if (counter == limit) {
    // Hash calculation begin -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var data : Data = Data ()
    for element in array {
      var item : Int = element
      data += Data (bytes : &(item), count : MemoryLayout<Int>.size )
    }
    // Hash calculation end -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    limit <<= 1
    print ("\(formatterInt.string (for : counter)!.leftPadding (13))  \(formatterDouble.string (for : (Double (elapsed) / 1_000_000_000.0))!.leftPadding (17))  \(SHA256.hash (data : data).compactMap { String (format : "%02x", $0) }.joined ())")
  }
}
while (counter < ROUND_MAX)
// Benchmark - end -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The results are somewhat daunting.

```
Array size : 1,000,000 elements

       Rounds        Elapsed (s)                                                     Hash (SHA256)
            1              0.002  138a3face9a95b3a5ba3f089b58c1e2067541e04fd5605841db62998a543ea29
            2              0.003  5b295b2183d1412143ea243610b5e8e6eb8f7253e7726aab4e840b64281d675a
            4              0.004  bb20a52f6730374c3e37d39b7e8ace180aa46aba3af87a454247c48c9f681e22
            8              0.007  d9f512c044e227d5f3df9343f1af7ec6297bd484c7ffb52b14c8acf9b65ba91b
           16              0.012  bbb1c4838300b3ae70227b4d85ab5de87f0dc75fd08a5bb48120a3703e391087
           32              0.024  f2930403b4ad701d76558eed0ef5a51973f7be7ac641157d7abb0e3c35e75f17
           64              0.045  80cb2479d11e2a83dcedca1f59bf11746fe0f513ee5a79cfb1c2e1f1a036d7bb
          128              0.092  e3c0495d8b2918bb65d1d33e5170ccc0f056b295ea912c1af46b410fc44e9796
          256              0.188  391d7ce33e0fc12f4c14928d55a3e869488a32ad580caf4cfdedbbbe3d7cb44f
          512              0.372  41d4c93d04437531ca1463a61608152369f23a2fbdc25780f2975446b51f857f
        1,024              0.752  f8287bec62c5fd41cdf3cc820f943688c31afc328aff8edf6a8e2a72060448d4
        2,048              1.508  c5de93d9d1c1f449184d46a56796600038a34d39ff97d582b5d6b85a0f5cc970
        4,096              3.009  3691fe4a09aba4a192cd7d1b3d9a99541230df1da0efc956a807d2960c129acf
        8,192              5.907  fcea1f69f59be2826f9894858d0ba0ca66728ab0d6a6bbc6ea2bc3bd7f884e7a
       16,384             11.753  68e40ebd65e232dcfbe8dda1867de2cfaa33cb79a24553dc590b94a6429aa804
       32,768             23.332  6168f321dcdc4e7457c383662b33067e5a70dac17a8c0d32903b801570316963
       65,536             46.451  e5526d34f40a43151b1848e16b203e35b1ba2c05dc104dc8f7394c26480f91f8
      131,072             92.733  cd7e7d27085f74f38800d40a4f6400998c3bf9a01e5dd76da57e6be48e50ceb7
      262,144            185.075  0b263633bd06999866994e2670c0094e63514190aaa2aa7437d9274c98d24dc6
      524,288            369.582  4d990804a9a39e5a31805c54479b669aec670ba10667c36bf7a5821d211e5e45
    1,048,576            739.025  f9c819e38bae6fcccadb19e6d5dc0194b924b4de758446cfb619c6733f027546
    2,097,152          1,476.831  3809b4ca104c051fbecdf8adf1c7b85e43f2bdf4a54f3a9fe0f6827fdf829b92
    4,194,304          2,951.803  52dcb8edef66f01fcd6a1a399d406bba799b353c8904ffe2206ebed7f366f872
    8,388,608          5,904.344  0b1103d71bf007d8e6308b70fa1c2699957ffd8eb2fb68105342fc20c037e37b
   16,777,216               *-->  Extrapolation:  11,808
   33,554,432               *-->  Extrapolation:  23,616
   67,108,864               *-->  Extrapolation:  47,232
  134,217,728               *-->  Extrapolation:  94,464
  268,435,456               *-->  Extrapolation: 188,928 (more than two days)
  536,870,912               *-->  Extrapolation: 377,856
1,073,741,824               *-->  Extrapolation: 755,712 (about nine days)
```

```
Array size : 10,000,000 elements

       Rounds        Elapsed (s)                                                     Hash (SHA256)
            1              0.003  f7c95ec2d5edc4661c3d66f9726282f3befc6596d7fb7c411278cc6bc1b867bf
            2              0.014  c7dd7d0a29dd54b716cd7bd50648316c5f9e8ea779dbad439384350eb44b06b2
            4              0.037  7848881cca4dd109f7d3c5332c0ef59d22d5d949e4c54c0744f43ec74c18bf27
            8              0.059  eeacab6470da127115d1d241f092214bb3ca979ea3c310810c433d64b75ab2c4
           16              0.142  6ba190fc0c23e0edca16ddda1c864c09f7780c12a6008b9ef44c29e4793ab538
           32              0.266  494025d36bccdc8423a309530ae58e35170cfc5c6dabfc64f8ed17b2c29d4f5d
           64              0.570  9a87b4572639785aef28c87f265abb6e8776161cd2220e4feac30f396baa2a16
          128              1.196  a56813198d4d1fc9848a02cb6b276bc2159422a0cce6d0d9cebdb11aa587457d
          256              2.328  1bb1aca5eb7230dda2c3b949fe916b5382a5f4db3d63dccabb4dce5e2858af94
          512              4.612  6b89ccda1d16976e5ef78706b4a0b2f5ceee9f1bd2f4ee239e1fe6ff1ba131e0
        1,024              9.455  f62d09dd8ddbebd9052660b33f864e3201a624f8113d8d0bbafc79fe06b28b54
        2,048             18.981  00b888459bed2d586ea2aa66095c9543f4383e3be7571146a7534807f832a901
        4,096             37.971  a70df557dc5104febab54918c29f2fe32e5b6eb741de54dc9b9c153929f6b710
        8,192             75.608  58ae33b7487febd6f806210e191a736415e292111f533b3cb19ece65cd285870
       16,384            151.125  d02009e5e858b0026ac3d7cccfc2392f852fb52b38797fb6ad3ff567f55d3344
       32,768            302.950  f16d5714bbc29de2423328303542da3276481185750a8e5c2d957c42d0b89ac3
       65,536            606.049  51c3f805a8e87fcaf2d394a381c72a821fcc79879e2da85d04f08044331d7276
      131,072          1,211.297  39a0c6fde176c1a01cf9ebcd3ae5c18e39aab6a9e0d6e8eca3ffd9df31f390f6
      262,144          2,423.513  28f0fae5f453cbe313eddc62d1c010482b1e07693f8a6cc1c33926e95929b98b
      524,288          4,851.429  0cc6cd6b129b21b21a281b3178b2f5192fd8556608a569db00361d3f8092dd90
    1,048,576               *-->  Extrapolation:     9,702
    2,097,152               *-->  Extrapolation:    19,404
    4,194,304               *-->  Extrapolation:    38,808
    8,388,608               *-->  Extrapolation:    77,616
   16,777,216               *-->  Extrapolation:   155,232 (about two days)
   33,554,432               *-->  Extrapolation:   310,464
   67,108,864               *-->  Extrapolation:   620,928 (about one week)
  134,217,728               *-->  Extrapolation: 1,241,856
  268,435,456               *-->  Extrapolation: 2,483,712 (about one month)
  536,870,912               *-->  Extrapolation: 4,967,424
1,073,741,824               *-->  Extrapolation: 9,934,848 (about four months)
```

```
Array size : 100,000,000 elements

       Rounds        Elapsed (s)                                                     Hash (SHA256)
            1              0.092  151e39fe153c331587677dadcbbe7d70e2b8d71c3a6691e3b89ac5e718287a47
            2              0.253  87505250156e85dbb89f8728d8ed2ea1c6bd64e27ab544b6d402e38ef1f710e4
            4              0.336  f4c544f12fb55d36dae203b20023fdb3114cbb9625657b8a09258d89959b97b2
            8              0.744  bc9e082a6c1cc773e5783d2a9703860d06be68fbae6d8f76ddd5d0eaf48ba84b
           16              1.473  1028a636e69bf2a920b81fb632e1b40c816c967938683dea9a3b5f02b418ec5a
           32              2.998  43aa5a981a15905229c2ca43cf0b6176364c160b5394c9a767f6e17a35a0fca4
           64              5.843  bed576d60984b6dbecac4852f897e90bc87d9ed595bd4a818367ae473ae5330a
          128             11.688  fd77e56b314dfb3baa0b6af269580d908d675a7c6a287b327de0529908ae0198
          256             23.995  bc2dc20d22edc68b5fb149d941328428bec00e94d1f3b60733a24f72fdcef1a9
          512             47.643  be1f23a307fdfa55648481f9932821339fd291d9ab6c6f5ff92641e341a27259
        1,024             95.298  973023792197d8f127a10fdad4f4fd9e833d8f859f215db9167be7cba348590d
        2,048            190.741  766e6970f7e6e454465faafbce570166454463878dae58861164ff9d32257c40
        4,096            381.089  7b96bc8e43e7f69ce69bed2f881381ba2bd7dc1e37ba32e8e15a224eebe636f4
        8,192            767.318  f25ece1854b8941a6c34de3ea6eb931bb7cf8644ee0c672d31eb8fd0d8e0ac4c
       16,384          1,541.048  0a7681ebf2d82c312c56e3d3e4cd4be61e6080799b9b8cca037e5daecc2df4d8
       32,768          3,097.719  315404e3bbd39a90fa0473fa126e8d30352566f81490704cccd0682ef08c7ffe
       65,536               *-->  Extrapolation:       6,196
      131,072               *-->  Extrapolation:      12,392
      262,144               *-->  Extrapolation:      24,784
      524,288               *-->  Extrapolation:      49,568
    1,048,576               *-->  Extrapolation:      99,136
    2,097,152               *-->  Extrapolation:     198,272 (more than two days)
    4,194,304               *-->  Extrapolation:     396,544
    8,388,608               *-->  Extrapolation:     793,088 (more than one week)
   16,777,216               *-->  Extrapolation:   1,586,176
   33,554,432               *-->  Extrapolation:   3,172,352 (more than a month)
   67,108,864               *-->  Extrapolation:   6,344,704
  134,217,728               *-->  Extrapolation:  12,689,408
  268,435,456               *-->  Extrapolation:  25,378,816 (about ten months)
  536,870,912               *-->  Extrapolation:  50,757,632
1,073,741,824               *-->  Extrapolation: 101,515,264 (more than three years)
```

Now, I have two questions:

**1) Is there a way to speed up the insertion/removal of elements - in random positions (neither appending nor prepending) - in arrays of the size I need?**

**2) If so, how?**

Thanks in avance.

Comment: Shouldn't you use special software that is designed for handling Big Data? I thought it was part of the definition of Big Data that normal data types aren't appropriate to use since they can't handle the amount of data.

Comment: Actually, these tests only confirm that Apple's documentation for arrays is correct and that insertions at random index indeed take O(n) time which is exactly what one should expect. As for your questions you should give more details about what you need from indexes storage to advise you on a more suitable data structure.

Comment: You can use fixed size array and just set a new value or nil for array elements instead of adding and removing elements of array. I sure that access by index for fixed size array is much faster then add/remove element operations for dynamic array.

Comment: You may want to look at Balanced tree data structures, which perform insertions at  log(n) time, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree

Comment: @Joakim Danielson This is a special case: the array only contains the offset of the records (of variable length) present in the SSDs. Multiple linear screenings are performed on the array in order to - with the help of other temporary structures (arrays, sets and dictionaries) - remove some elements (and eventually reinsert them in previous positions), based on variable criteria. The final result (the offset sequence) is then used as a basis for subsequent processing (which I do not deal with).

Comment: @AlexSmet This way is not feasible, as the removal of an element must involve the realignment of the indices of all subsequent elements. For instance, in an array of 20 elements, storing a nil value in the element with index 10 would not change the index of the next element (will remain 11 and should instead become 10), and all subsequents. The same applies in case of insertion: in the test program it's executed a removal followed by an insertion, but only for simplify the test, because in reality there can be hundreds or thousands of consecutive removals, followed by as many insertions.

Comment: @Konstantin Oznobihin I found in the web - some time ago - news about the implementation of random access linked lists in Python, but it seems that they was not working properly (too much bugs) and the library that supported them is not maintained from long time (years). I was hoping something equivalent had been implemented in Swift.

Comment: @P2000 Even this way is not practicable (we already tried it): the elements present in the array cannot be sorted in any way (there are no criterias or discriminants). Condition - this - necessary in order to use structures such as the balanced trees.

Comment: Adriana, I am not sure then what the problem statement is. If the elements are "not sorted in any way" (did you mean "ordered"?) then why does it matter where the insertion happens? I think for readers here to help with the Swift aspect, we should first better understand the underlying structure (linking) of the data. Perhaps you can illustrate it with 10 elements first?

Comment: @P2000 I repeat here - to better explain - what I wrote in a comment on Charles's answer. Imagine a sequence of DNA genes in which there are repeats of the same gene. Once a point has been reached - in the array - an element is deleted within the array itself. Next, you need to go back - in the array - of a number of positions (sometimes tens of millions) and make an insertion. And then advance another number of positions and make another insertion and so on.

Comment: @P2000 I would use an array (and not - for instance - a linked list) because you can always know your current position and therefore you can access the next element with a simple addition or subtraction. P.S.: yes, with "sorted" I mean "ordered" (sorry for my bad english).

Comment: @Adriana it's still not clear what kind of processing you need to do. Off the top of my head you might try to make a new array with all deletions and insertions applied at once. It would still take O(n) time, but you'd have to pay it only once, it won't be multiplied by the number of changes to the array.

Answer (score 1):

About your **first** question

> 1) Is there a way to speed up the insertion/removal of elements - in random positions (neither appending nor prepending) - in arrays of the size I need?

the **only one** I can answer: **yes there is**, using a proprietary algorithm that is implemented in both Swift and C++.

Replacing, in your code:

`var array : Array<Int> = Array<Int> ()`

with:

`var array : StripeArray<Int> = StripeArray<Int> ()`

the results are:

```
Array size : 1,000,000 elements

       Rounds        Elapsed (s)                                                     Hash (SHA256)
            1              0.000  138a3face9a95b3a5ba3f089b58c1e2067541e04fd5605841db62998a543ea29
            2              0.000  5b295b2183d1412143ea243610b5e8e6eb8f7253e7726aab4e840b64281d675a
            4              0.000  bb20a52f6730374c3e37d39b7e8ace180aa46aba3af87a454247c48c9f681e22
            8              0.000  d9f512c044e227d5f3df9343f1af7ec6297bd484c7ffb52b14c8acf9b65ba91b
           16              0.000  bbb1c4838300b3ae70227b4d85ab5de87f0dc75fd08a5bb48120a3703e391087
           32              0.000  f2930403b4ad701d76558eed0ef5a51973f7be7ac641157d7abb0e3c35e75f17
           64              0.001  80cb2479d11e2a83dcedca1f59bf11746fe0f513ee5a79cfb1c2e1f1a036d7bb
          128              0.001  e3c0495d8b2918bb65d1d33e5170ccc0f056b295ea912c1af46b410fc44e9796
          256              0.002  391d7ce33e0fc12f4c14928d55a3e869488a32ad580caf4cfdedbbbe3d7cb44f
          512              0.003  41d4c93d04437531ca1463a61608152369f23a2fbdc25780f2975446b51f857f
        1,024              0.005  f8287bec62c5fd41cdf3cc820f943688c31afc328aff8edf6a8e2a72060448d4
        2,048              0.009  c5de93d9d1c1f449184d46a56796600038a34d39ff97d582b5d6b85a0f5cc970
        4,096              0.017  3691fe4a09aba4a192cd7d1b3d9a99541230df1da0efc956a807d2960c129acf
        8,192              0.032  fcea1f69f59be2826f9894858d0ba0ca66728ab0d6a6bbc6ea2bc3bd7f884e7a
       16,384              0.060  68e40ebd65e232dcfbe8dda1867de2cfaa33cb79a24553dc590b94a6429aa804
       32,768              0.121  6168f321dcdc4e7457c383662b33067e5a70dac17a8c0d32903b801570316963
       65,536              0.248  e5526d34f40a43151b1848e16b203e35b1ba2c05dc104dc8f7394c26480f91f8
      131,072              0.500  cd7e7d27085f74f38800d40a4f6400998c3bf9a01e5dd76da57e6be48e50ceb7
      262,144              0.945  0b263633bd06999866994e2670c0094e63514190aaa2aa7437d9274c98d24dc6
      524,288              1.999  4d990804a9a39e5a31805c54479b669aec670ba10667c36bf7a5821d211e5e45
    1,048,576              3.989  f9c819e38bae6fcccadb19e6d5dc0194b924b4de758446cfb619c6733f027546
    2,097,152              7.891  3809b4ca104c051fbecdf8adf1c7b85e43f2bdf4a54f3a9fe0f6827fdf829b92
    4,194,304             15.938  52dcb8edef66f01fcd6a1a399d406bba799b353c8904ffe2206ebed7f366f872
    8,388,608             32.122  0b1103d71bf007d8e6308b70fa1c2699957ffd8eb2fb68105342fc20c037e37b
   16,777,216             64.380  dc29acbf1aa86925035e69b7c455a53baba83f690e533845a8b502003adc8450
   33,554,432            129.038  9fb6b8485f471547e87eae282dbb4303f52390e88f3ee391de81f1bb342fd89a
   67,108,864            252.159  27f3dcc51ab55b40c9c7bec411c42970004f493fc6435ff1741d04355092837c
  134,217,728            497.752  07875954033e7909343a09bdaf1d300c211a14468e6dbed48ee143cf8d4f30e3
  268,435,456            987.026  6dd13e92d482cab418ce8aaf1248972859f4e107669a582122c20725566693cf
  536,870,912          1,965.029  398bca13e5de89725e3acf30435ff40cdd35a81c0c8c3e32b0fce705849eafc0
1,073,741,824          3,927.479  42897b3575eb945729ebf4db6ec6554e4efa4d0c32c2969d2bde0f9180118a17
```

```
Array size : 10,000,000 elements

       Rounds        Elapsed (s)                                                     Hash (SHA256)
            1              0.000  f7c95ec2d5edc4661c3d66f9726282f3befc6596d7fb7c411278cc6bc1b867bf
            2              0.000  c7dd7d0a29dd54b716cd7bd50648316c5f9e8ea779dbad439384350eb44b06b2
            4              0.000  7848881cca4dd109f7d3c5332c0ef59d22d5d949e4c54c0744f43ec74c18bf27
            8              0.000  eeacab6470da127115d1d241f092214bb3ca979ea3c310810c433d64b75ab2c4
           16              0.000  6ba190fc0c23e0edca16ddda1c864c09f7780c12a6008b9ef44c29e4793ab538
           32              0.000  494025d36bccdc8423a309530ae58e35170cfc5c6dabfc64f8ed17b2c29d4f5d
           64              0.001  9a87b4572639785aef28c87f265abb6e8776161cd2220e4feac30f396baa2a16
          128              0.001  a56813198d4d1fc9848a02cb6b276bc2159422a0cce6d0d9cebdb11aa587457d
          256              0.002  1bb1aca5eb7230dda2c3b949fe916b5382a5f4db3d63dccabb4dce5e2858af94
          512              0.003  6b89ccda1d16976e5ef78706b4a0b2f5ceee9f1bd2f4ee239e1fe6ff1ba131e0
        1,024              0.006  f62d09dd8ddbebd9052660b33f864e3201a624f8113d8d0bbafc79fe06b28b54
        2,048              0.011  00b888459bed2d586ea2aa66095c9543f4383e3be7571146a7534807f832a901
        4,096              0.021  a70df557dc5104febab54918c29f2fe32e5b6eb741de54dc9b9c153929f6b710
        8,192              0.041  58ae33b7487febd6f806210e191a736415e292111f533b3cb19ece65cd285870
       16,384              0.079  d02009e5e858b0026ac3d7cccfc2392f852fb52b38797fb6ad3ff567f55d3344
       32,768              0.154  f16d5714bbc29de2423328303542da3276481185750a8e5c2d957c42d0b89ac3
       65,536              0.296  51c3f805a8e87fcaf2d394a381c72a821fcc79879e2da85d04f08044331d7276
      131,072              0.584  39a0c6fde176c1a01cf9ebcd3ae5c18e39aab6a9e0d6e8eca3ffd9df31f390f6
      262,144              1.155  28f0fae5f453cbe313eddc62d1c010482b1e07693f8a6cc1c33926e95929b98b
      524,288              2.255  0cc6cd6b129b21b21a281b3178b2f5192fd8556608a569db00361d3f8092dd90
    1,048,576              4.445  756149d37c140d78f8b4c4f2712fc68ea7772e6d6b7a570ffbff8a0d7feb9536
    2,097,152              8.900  1679c7ab94837dd0b6de25de9f0514ddab59c2f120fde2dd94994d5b6913cfa6
    4,194,304             18.086  92c2c6b3f0ec42f064ead4cb8be16143d176ab8a518158ff2a7647ca108b972d
    8,388,608             37.057  b9f27d2ae85764f614b28763ab5bd008cdc59f01c0c31d05b58396b8f05d76f9
   16,777,216             76.743  e6f60c5fb26fbf9ff03136a414cf27103ed90689bd584748bab4fa3be6d2be56
   33,554,432            161.223  077c729b4faf748469d8ef59cf8292e321c2bb3b1b418df2cdcb6f2dca0896d9
   67,108,864            334.968  1b43867529d0e2044728eacac88f4167f02448ccc73e120f0dce7b942ab3360c
  134,217,728            709.715  7ea104ee3a88f45c412eac5e83e4fa2412e8eab9f5e666fc9b19462053b62437
  268,435,456          1,463.908  792745cc6cb6e062b4fbbd83da45d6a1a6be4c7d0df72c266c884118338489e0
  536,870,912          2,968.155  525880fc64d5d4e3fa413313b6ed8db70d7baef959523dec2aba20a4829b371f
1,073,741,824          5,924.369  c09fb4ef535acfe1d3ac67d34da68ce1fb360f080d0c2af4bae2535b819bd963
```

```
Array size : 100,000,000 elements

       Rounds        Elapsed (s)                                                     Hash (SHA256)
            1              0.000  151e39fe153c331587677dadcbbe7d70e2b8d71c3a6691e3b89ac5e718287a47
            2              0.000  87505250156e85dbb89f8728d8ed2ea1c6bd64e27ab544b6d402e38ef1f710e4
            4              0.000  f4c544f12fb55d36dae203b20023fdb3114cbb9625657b8a09258d89959b97b2
            8              0.000  bc9e082a6c1cc773e5783d2a9703860d06be68fbae6d8f76ddd5d0eaf48ba84b
           16              0.000  1028a636e69bf2a920b81fb632e1b40c816c967938683dea9a3b5f02b418ec5a
           32              0.000  43aa5a981a15905229c2ca43cf0b6176364c160b5394c9a767f6e17a35a0fca4
           64              0.001  bed576d60984b6dbecac4852f897e90bc87d9ed595bd4a818367ae473ae5330a
          128              0.001  fd77e56b314dfb3baa0b6af269580d908d675a7c6a287b327de0529908ae0198
          256              0.002  bc2dc20d22edc68b5fb149d941328428bec00e94d1f3b60733a24f72fdcef1a9
          512              0.004  be1f23a307fdfa55648481f9932821339fd291d9ab6c6f5ff92641e341a27259
        1,024              0.008  973023792197d8f127a10fdad4f4fd9e833d8f859f215db9167be7cba348590d
        2,048              0.015  766e6970f7e6e454465faafbce570166454463878dae58861164ff9d32257c40
        4,096              0.030  7b96bc8e43e7f69ce69bed2f881381ba2bd7dc1e37ba32e8e15a224eebe636f4
        8,192              0.058  f25ece1854b8941a6c34de3ea6eb931bb7cf8644ee0c672d31eb8fd0d8e0ac4c
       16,384              0.114  0a7681ebf2d82c312c56e3d3e4cd4be61e6080799b9b8cca037e5daecc2df4d8
       32,768              0.224  315404e3bbd39a90fa0473fa126e8d30352566f81490704cccd0682ef08c7ffe
       65,536              0.439  7958a9d47987cc4b29f8553c1eafb6fe19f9cf11f2ba772b3457be9c3311216c
      131,072              0.861  95a96ec79d7c92e8604142086718c698a2cb34b4aa8124230c46df2a4715a422
      262,144              1.703  40e83d974fb31f9e6f35d8c1814efad5a4faa5fa35c59b6f69a3c30ffb514ea4
      524,288              3.359  b6ae9ea226e172a4996a0b2c89ea83b8376526ae4a9f05c66c1f4c9e30b550de
    1,048,576              6.661  745be68c43083483fc46754af91f7b846f03db9c734eef32829a8b6ec5203234
    2,097,152             13.218  07429d7cc93ede5aa0c4f476a7be9ede5486320f37713af160a683b12e5740a7
    4,194,304             26.257  55d2f463d80c4ed9e1ae5c8ee7d247e47c8e06c70c728b7aab3602197b432476
    8,388,608             52.382  7bbe659baa1ac668ab338b14ff64d49bb8885e3ad6aa887db26392da1475076a
   16,777,216            106.178  6ca8d0b131efcc14d2d2b5824e3000d9a86718912b955f4a4f8bd3d552219469
   33,554,432            218.220  5740bc9a875c5bc7cd609c66e53cf10462ca26a75c7cbf9b640e99059a3706ec
   67,108,864            454.537  ee9b38491cb077502e35db6e5a7565f4e81f9f596913524078ae1cc135ed4fb6
  134,217,728            960.702  c863999ae6b25bcf913e795b1d17f81a7362a966b495ed72498d3e47c56ad99e
  268,435,456          2,069.102  12ae018fb2b8139713512960179172d8f1eae7f795933cdcd0d259cd06748ff9
  536,870,912          4,403.656  23b0927ac1631b5fa757695f16df7a4f03077f037c88a2ff1e99a07e8b737ece
1,073,741,824          9,138.401  d0312a0608dc735fb1ebde9cc9009afdc7bb16c8e5e2c8965c9b73cdcf741bce
```

The proportions between Swift's Arrays and StripeArrays performance are:

```
+-------------+---------------------+
|    Size     | Array : StripeArray |
+-------------+---------------------+
|   1,000,000 |        192 : 1      |
|  10,000,000 |      1,677 : 1      |
| 100,000,000 |     11,105 : 1      |
+-------------+---------------------+
```

I have also produced a comparison chart in PDF, between the results you have obtained and those I have obtained with the StripeArray, available at the following link:

https://www.skyware.eu/StackOverflow/ArrayVsStripeArray.pdf

Comment: I ran my test program again for a longer period (a dozen hours of processing) and now I can confirm some of your results. They are amazing!!! These StripeArrays are what I need. Where can I find them?

Comment: You can't. The algorithm behind the two implementations is proprietary and not yet patented: it isn't open-source.
Alternatively you can try to use the Skip-List, although they are probabilistic and not deterministic they can give you the speed increase you need. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list